# linq select from array name with value

Tags: c#, linq

Hi having array of ints like `ages int[]{123, 234}`

how to select it to string which can be used as get request `ages=123&ages=234`

Comment: ``ages`` constant in request must the same of the variable name or i can use constant like ``ages``?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a combination of `string.Join` and `Select`:

`string.Join("&", ages.Select(age => $"ages={age}"));`

Answer (score 1):

To do proper URL encoding, you can use [`HttpUtility.ParseQueryString()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httputility.parsequerystring?view=netframework-4.8) like this:

```cs
var query = System.Web.HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(string.Empty);

foreach (var age in ages)
{
    query.Add("ages", age.ToString());
}

// or: ages.ToList().ForEach(age => query.Add("ages", age.ToString()));

return query.ToString();
```

However, this will lead to `ages=123,234`.